# sudo: ./<SomeBinary>: command not found when run from mounted folder

Tags: permissions, sudo

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12996397/command-not-found-when-using-sudo is exactly what I am looking for but none of the answers worked for me. I am using Arch Linux. I am trying to run a command in the present working directory

```
Workspace$ sudo ./SomeBinary -some_args
sudo: ./<SomeBinary>: command not found
sudo pwd
/home/SomeUser/Workspace
```

My `/etc/sudoers` file

```
Defaults env_keep += "LANG LANGUAGE LINGUAS LC_* _XKB_CHARSET"
Defaults env_keep += "HOME"
Defaults env_keep += "XAPPLRESDIR XFILESEARCHPATH XUSERFILESEARCHPATH"
Defaults env_keep += "QTDIR KDEDIR"
Defaults env_keep += "XDG_SESSION_COOKIE"
Defaults env_keep += "XMODIFIERS GTK_IM_MODULE QT_IM_MODULE QT_IM_SWITCHER"
Defaults secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"

Defaults mail_badpass
Defaults log_output
Defaults!/usr/bin/sudoreplay !log_output
Defaults!/usr/local/bin/sudoreplay !log_output
Defaults!REBOOT !log_output

root ALL=(ALL) ALL

%wheel ALL=(ALL) ALL

%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

I have mounted the working directory with remote directory using `sshfs`.

```
sshfs RemoteUbuntu.local:/media/ExtHDD/Workspace ~/Workspace
```

Remote is `BTRFS` formated.

Comment: What's the binary you're trying to run?

Comment: can you `ls -l /home/SomeUser/Workspace`?  Is it possible the binary isn't in that directory?  Or maybe you don't have execute permissions on it?

Comment: If it's a shell script, does the she-bang executor exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's something else at play here, I suspect with the `./SomeBinary`. I ran these two tests on a CentOS 7 box using `sudo` and they both worked without issue.

```
$ cat sudy.bash
#!/bin/bash

whoami
echo "hi"
pwd
```

Which results in this output:

```
$ sudo ./sudy.bash
root
hi
/home/vagrant
```

And if I copied the `whoami` executable to my `/home/vagrant` directory and ran it:

```
$ which whoami
/usr/bin/whoami

$ cp /usr/bin/whoami .

$ ll whoami
-rwxr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant 28984 Aug  5 00:23 whoami
```

And when I run it via `sudo`:

```
$ sudo ./whoami
root
```

#### Command not found

Curiously the only way I could induce that message with `sudo` is when the execute bit is removed from my `sudy.bash` script. For example:

```
$ chmod -x sudy.bash
```

*run as myself*

```
$ ./sudy.bash
-bash: ./sudy.bash: Permission denied
```

*run via sudo*

```
$ sudo ./sudy.bash
sudo: ./sudy.bash: command not found
```

**NOTE:** The same thing happens with the copied `sudo ./whoami` as well.

Comment: Yeah, My working directory is mounted with `sshfs`! When I am running it from a plain directory, `sudo` executes good. Thanks! Can you suggest how to make it work on mounted directory?

Comment: @neckTwi - can you provide the output of `df -h .` for where you're running `sudo`? Also why not mention that critical detail in the Q? Seems odd that you wouldn't mention such a pivotal piece of info.

Comment: @neckTwi - what's the `sshfs` mounting command look like? I mounted a remote directory in this manner and ran `whoami` over the mounted share and it works fine.

Comment: The executable that's failing is apparently on a mounted sshfs  - https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-sshfs-to-mount-remote-file-systems-over-ssh.

Comment: My bad, I should have mentioned it. I have updated the question. Thank you!

Comment: `sudo sshfs -o allow_other,IdentityFile=/home/SomeOne/.ssh/id_rsa SomeOne@:RemoteUbuntu.local/media/ExtHDD/Workspace ~/Workspace` worked. `-o allow_other,defer_permissions` coughs `fuse: unknown option(s): '-o defer_permissions'`

Comment: @neckTwi - defer_permissions didn't work for me either.